# Using jquery hover event half working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is my code:

```
$("a.boton").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).html(function (i, origText) {
            return "<i class='fi-check'>&#xf126;</i>" + origText;
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).html(function (i, origText) {
            return origText.replace("<i class='fi-check'>&#xf126;</i>", "");
        });
    }
);
```

It's adding that `<i>` nestle on `<a>` so it's half working but I can't make it delete the `<i>` when visitors mouse isn't over, can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you make http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s60pj58c/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add this

```
$("a.boton").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).find("i").remove();
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/s60pj58c/3/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use of `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` works perfectly instead of `hover()`. In cases where you want to rollback the changes done on hovering mouse.